# How to adjust Reveal BI chart/legend font size?

Tags: html, frontend, reveal.js

I am trying to adjust the font size of the chart legends in my Reveal Bi dashboard.

Code block below works except for the 'font-size' property.

```
<div #revealView style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative; font-size: 20px"></div>
```

I have checked Reveal Bi documentation and am unsure if the properties for font size can be accessed. I am just trying to make the font size larger as it is very small.

Thank you in advance.